# Xcode/Swift - Me carga incorrectamente el Svg con la libreria SDWebImageSVGKitPlugin

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy descargando una serie de imagenes SVG usando la libreria "SDWebImageSVGKitPlugin" pero solo me muestra un color azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la imagen deberia ser algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
if self.notificaciones!.notificaciones![indexPath.row].datos!.image_url != nil {
        let url = URL(string: self.notificaciones!.notificaciones![indexPath.row].datos!.image_url!)
        let svgImageSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 40)
        
        //cell.imageIndicator.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
        
        
        cell.imageIndicator.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: [], context: [.imageThumbnailPixelSize : svgImageSize], progress: nil, completed:{ image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
            cell.imageIndicator.image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        })
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Cómo tienes los contraints de esa imagen con respecto a los labels y al contenedor?

Comment: La UIImageView tiene dos constraints al contenedor uno superior y otro a la derecha, y ningun label esta unido por algun constraint al UIImageView

Comment: De prueba puedes agregar el constraint de width y height a la imagen.

Comment: a si tambien tiene el constraint de width y height